# I'm using the OpenAI API, but the localhost server isn't running

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I'm using the OpenAI API, and I'm trying to get a localhost server running. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Why is this?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
const express = require('express');
require("dotenv").config();
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const configuration = new Configuration({
apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

app.post("/find-complexity", async (req, res) => {
try {
return res.status(200).json({
message: "Working",
});
} catch (error) {}
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server listening on port 3000"));
```

I ran it through both a terminal and postman, but neither worked. When I ran `npm run dev` through the terminal, an error came up, stating:

```
const configuration = new Configuration({
                      ^

TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor
```

When I ran the server through postman, with the input being `localhost:3000/find-complexity`, the following error came up: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions of this SDK used a `Configuration` class. See [v3 to v4 migration guide.](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217)

```js
// Old
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// New
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY // This is also the default, can be omitted
});
```

See [real-world example](https://github.com/danny-avila/LibreChat/blob/0bae503a0ab99ee71b367a11f2a79e5663262420/api/server/routes/assistants/assistants.js#L13) about how to use `openai` v4.x

Comment: There's an error when I run `npm run dev`. It's: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @jomosh Use `require` instead of `import`